# for /f "the system cannot find the file" in windows command script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having some difficulty with "for /f" not being able to find a file with a specific name.  Many users on this site had this problem when the file or path contained spaces, but that is not the case here.  Simple example, batch file named "test4.cmd":

```
 @echo off
 set ln=%1
 if exist 2013_10_23_Cal_Curve.txt echo The first file exists.
 if exist ~temp1.txt echo The second file exists.
 for /f "skip=%ln% tokens=2" %%a in (2013_10_23_Cal_Curve.txt) do echo Found the first file.
 for /f "skip=%ln% tokens=2" %%a in (~temp1.txt) do echo Found the second file.
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\wnc7\Desktop\jmp_test_data>test4 1
The first file exists.
The second file exists.
The system cannot find the file 2013_10_23_Cal_Curve.txt.
Found the second file.
Found the second file.
Found the second file.
*(expected output continues for second file....)*
```

Other commands such as findstr can find the file, but for/f cannot find it.  Yet for/f can find ~temp1.txt written in the same format, and in the same directory.

I have tried "usebackq" and putting the file name in quotes, to no avail.  Any help is appreciated.

Mike

Comment: just show the content of `2013_10_23_Cal_Curve.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

The file is read blocked by another process. If it can't be readed, it exists, and can be find, but `for /f` can not process it. Instead of for command, try `type file` or `delete file`, then the error will be that the system has no access to the file because it is in use by another process.

Comment: This was the problem.  The first file was locked by another program and I didn't realize it.  The error message was a bit deceptive, wasn't it?  Thanks so much for the help, as it was driving me crazy!